# netbeans web services generated using WSDL, return method

Tags: soap, netbeans, service, response

I am pretty new to web services and i've started working on a little project where i need to develope some web-services where i send a request to mysql db to retrieve some records now i've done most it meaning i've been able to generate web services using WSDL through netbeans and connect to database and retrieve records the only problem is soap response is not the format i want it come:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:topScorerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www..co/">
         <playersName>John Doe</playersName>
         <playersName>John Doe</playersName>
         <playersName>John Doe</playersName>
         <teamName>Fulham</teamName>
         <teamName>Liverpool</teamName>
         <teamName>Arsenal</teamName>
         <goals>10</goals>
         <goals>20</goals>
         <goals>11</goals>
      </ns2:topScorerResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

but i am looking for something like:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
 <S:Body>
      <ns2:topScorerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www..co/">
         <playersName>John Doe</playersName>
         <teamName>Liverpool</>
         <goals>10</>
      </ns2:topScorerResponse>
      <ns2:topScorerResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www..co/">
         <playersName>John Doe</playersName>
         <teamName>Fulham</>
         <goals>11</goals>
      </ns2:topScorerResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```